# css not working to put image at the right of the text

Tags: html, css

I have an image and would like to put my text on its right. 
I have the code below, why isn't it working?
 My fiddle:
 http://jsfiddle.net/a2kjtuet/2/#&togetherjs=zvUcL6sQOE

```
.posText { 
 position: absolute; 
 top: 200px; 
 left: 0; 
 width: 100%; 
 }
```

```
  <img src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100"/>

  <h4> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h4>    
  <p>Vestibulum vehicula odio quis ante pellentesque pharetra. Duis congue nibh in nisl iaculis iaculis. Nunc cursus est ut leo sollicitudin euismod.<br>

  Maecenas commodo dui sed interdum placerat. Duis nec semper nunc. Fusce at  volutpat eros.Etiam tincidunt nulla ut mauris pellentesque, nec ullamcorper  dolor scelerisque. Praesent semper pharetra viverra. <br>

  <b>Ut fermentum sodales felis quis rutrum.</b>
  </p>

  </div>
```

Comment: working for me in chrome. where is the text for you?

Comment: underneath and I am on chrome too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **CSS Flexbox**. Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.posText {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.text-container {
  margin-left: 10px;
} 

h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="posText">
  
      <img src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100"/>    
  <div class="text-container">
      <h4> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h4>

<p>Vestibulum vehicula odio quis ante pellentesque pharetra. Duis congue nibh in nisl iaculis iaculis. Nunc cursus est ut leo sollicitudin euismod.<br>

Maecenas commodo dui sed interdum placerat. Duis nec semper nunc. Fusce at volutpat eros.Etiam tincidunt nulla ut mauris pellentesque, nec ullamcorper dolor scelerisque. Praesent semper pharetra viverra. <br>
 
<b>Ut fermentum sodales felis quis rutrum.</b>
</p>

</div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

style the image with a float left

```
  <img style="float:left;"  src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100"/>
```